# Add custom column to the Order Grid for export

Tags: orders, sales-order, magento2.2, export, order-grid

I want to add some custom field like **sku** to add in order grid to export along with the order.

I follow this link [Add custom product attribute to Order Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206744/add-custom-product-attribute-to-order-grid)  to do this, but this didn't work in this Magento version.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the code compilation and cache. Run command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

and now my custom columns are showing in order grid and also export with other order data.